# updateSelectInput in R Shiny module won't pass existing inputs to 'selected' argument

Tags: r, module, shiny

I'm writing an app that will help wrangle data files into standard formats to feed reusable dashboards. Part of this effort involves creating a user interface to make it easy for users to map the random column names they have in their input files to the "standard" column names that the dashboard is going to expect.

I actually got this code working nicely. But the app needs to do this same mapping exercise for several different input files (each with their own set of standard column names), so it seemed like a good candidate to modularize!

Here's the workflow:

1. The user loads a "mapping input" file. If they've done this mapping
   exercise before, I want to use this file to pre-populate the
   drop-downs. I'm also pulling the list of standard column names from
   this table. Each standard column name gets an associated drop down.
2. They load their file to be wrangled - the one with the wackly column
       names. The column names in this file will become the options in the
       drop-downs.
3. As the user starts mapping their column names to the different
   standard name drop downs, their selections will disappear from the
   other drop-down lists. This makes it easier to map columns in files
   with many columns.

I feel like I am so close. The issue is when the module runs updateSelectInput. I'm using updateSelectInput to remove options from the drop-downs that have already been used. This works, but it clears out the pre-populated values that were set in the renderUI function.

Here's the code with the pre-populated values working (having removed the problematic updateSelectInput):

```
# Load libraries and options ----------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Modules -----------------------------------------------------------------

input_ui <- function(id, row_label, file_description) {
    ns <- NS(id) 
    fluidRow(
        uiOutput(ns("colmapping")) # References the dynamic dropdowns created by the server module.
    )
}


# Creates dynamic dropdowns which ultimately will be used to rename columns from a number of different files.
input_server <- function(input, output, session, parent) {

    # Create a fake file with misnamed columns that need remapped. 
    input_file <- reactive({
            return(data.frame(Account.Number = 1:2,
                              Account.Name = c("Account 1", "Account 2"),
                              Quota.2018 = c(1000, 2000)))
    })

    # Get a list of what the columns SHOULD be named. These will also do double-duty as the labels for our dropdown inputs.
    standard_columns <- reactive({ 
        c("AccountId", "AccountName", "SalesGoal")
    })

    # Get the actual column names from the file with misnamed columns.
    actual_columns <- reactive({
        colnames(input_file())
    })

    # A separate input can be loaded that documents how the misnamed columns have been mapped to the correct names in the past. 
    # We want to pre-populate the dropdowns with these selections.
    quickstart_columns <- reactive({
        c("Account.Number", "Account.Name", "Quota")
    })

    # Create a drop-down selectInput for each of the "standard" column names, allowing the user to choose from the column names in their own misnamed file.
    output$colmapping <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        dropdowns = tagList()
        for (i in seq_len(length(standard_columns()))) { # For i in 1:number of standard names associated with this table
            dropdowns[[i]] = selectInput(ns(paste0("input_", standard_columns()[i])), # Use the standard name value for the input object name
                                         label = paste0(standard_columns()[i]), # And for the UI label
                                         choices = actual_columns(),
                                         selected = quickstart_columns()[i],
                                         multiple = FALSE) #Use choices from loaded input table
        }
        return(dropdowns)
    })
}

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------


ui <- fluidPage(
    input_ui("acct_info")
)


# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    acct_info_mod_results <- callModule(input_server, 
                                        "acct_info", 
                                        parent = session)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here's the same code with updateSelectInput turned on (so selected-elsewhere options drop from the choices), but where the pre-populated values don't show up.

```
# Load libraries and options ----------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Modules -----------------------------------------------------------------

input_ui <- function(id, row_label, file_description) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    fluidRow(
        uiOutput(ns("colmapping")) # References the dynamic dropdowns created by the server module.
    )
}


# Creates dynamic dropdowns which ultimately will be used to rename columns from a number of different files.
input_server <- function(input, output, session, parent) {

    # Create a fake file with misnamed columns that need remapped. 
    input_file <- reactive({
            return(data.frame(Account.Number = 1:2,
                              Account.Name = c("Account 1", "Account 2"),
                              Quota.2018 = c(1000, 2000)))
    })

    # Get a list of what the columns SHOULD be named. These will also do double-duty as the labels for our dropdown inputs.
    standard_columns <- reactive({ 
        c("AccountId", "AccountName", "SalesGoal")
    })

    # Get the actual column names from the file with misnamed columns.
    actual_columns <- reactive({
        colnames(input_file())
    })

    # A separate input can be loaded that documents how the misnamed columns have been mapped to the correct names in the past. 
    # We want to pre-populate the dropdowns with these selections.
    quickstart_columns <- reactive({
        c("Account.Number", "Account.Name", "Quota")
    })

    # Create a drop-down selectInput for each of the "standard" column names, allowing the user to choose from the column names in their own misnamed file.
    output$colmapping <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        dropdowns = tagList()
        for (i in seq_len(length(standard_columns()))) { # For i in 1:number of standard names associated with this table
            dropdowns[[i]] = selectInput(ns(paste0("input_", standard_columns()[i])), # Use the standard name value for the input object name
                                         label = paste0(standard_columns()[i]), # And for the UI label
                                         choices = actual_columns(),
                                         selected = quickstart_columns()[i],
                                         multiple = FALSE) #Use choices from loaded input table
        }
        return(dropdowns)
    })

    # This is the chunk of code giving me trouble!
    # For some of these files, there's like 20-some columns that will need renamed. That's a lot of scanning through long dropdown lists.
    # As the user starts to map some of the columns, I want their selections to disappear from the other drop downs.
    # The good news is, this works!
    # The bad news is, it also clears out the pre-populated inputs. How can I keep the pre-populated inputs from disappearing when I apply updateSelectInput?

    observe({

        ns <- session$ns
        n <- isolate(length(standard_columns()))
        for (i in seq_len(n)) {
            already_selected <- unlist(lapply((1:n)[-i], function(i)
                input[[ paste0("input_",standard_columns()[i]) ]]))

            print(i)
            selected_i <- input[[ paste0("input_", standard_columns()[i]) ]]
            print(selected_i) # For debugging. These return empty values until selections are made, but I never had the problem with analogous code until I tried to put it in the module.
            updateSelectInput(session = parent,
                              ns(paste0("input_",standard_columns()[i])),
                              choices = append(c("Empty"),setdiff(actual_columns(), already_selected)),
                              selected = input[[ paste0("input_", standard_columns()[i]) ]]
            )
        }
    })


}

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------


ui <- fluidPage(
    input_ui("acct_info")
)


# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    acct_info_mod_results <- callModule(input_server, 
                                        "acct_info", 
                                        parent = session)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is the first time I've gotten so totally stuck on a project!! I hugely appreciate any insight or suggestions!

EDIT: After much pain, I've figured out how to get a list of session inputs that I can loop through to create the updateSelectInput in the parent session. I've also figured out how to put it into a function in the main session. Here's a minimal example of the working fix, but I'm all ears if anyone has a smarter way to solve the problem!

```
# Load libraries and options ----------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

updateDropDowns <- function(session, all_inputs) {

  inputs <-  setdiff(all_inputs$names, all_inputs$names %>% str_subset(pattern="selectize"))
  selected <- unname(unlist(all_inputs %>% filter(names %in% inputs) %>% select(selected)))
  values <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

  n <- length(inputs)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {

      already_selected <- unlist(lapply((1:n)[-i], function(i)
      selected[i]))

    updateSelectInput(session,
                      inputs[i],
                      choices = setdiff(values, already_selected),
                      selected = selected[i])
  }
}

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------


ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("colmapping")
)


# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$colmapping <- renderUI({
    dropdowns = tagList()
    for (i in 1:3) { 
      dropdowns[[i]] = selectInput(paste0("input_",i), 
                                   label = paste0("input_",i), 
                                   choices = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                                   selected = NULL,
                                   multiple = FALSE) 
    }
    return(dropdowns)
  })

  all_inputs <- reactive({ # get a dataframe of input names and values, else return an empty df 
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    y <- data.frame(
      names = names(x),
      selected = unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)
    )
    empty <- as.data.frame(setNames(rbind(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 1)),
                                          c(rep("999",2))),
                                    c("names", "selected")))
    if(nrow(y) == 0) {empty} else {y}
  })

  observe({
    updateDropDowns(session, all_inputs())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example with unrelated codes removed? If your example code snippet is shorter, more people will be willing to help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I've just whittled it down further to simplify all of the inputs and just keep the pieces critical to the problem.